# Pytorch hidden state LSTM

Tags: lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

Why do we need to initialize the hidden state h0 in LSTM in pytorch. As h0 will anyways be calculated and get overwritten ? Isn't it like

int a
a = 0

a = 4

Even if we do not do a=0, it should be fine..

Comment: nemo's answer is accurate. For completion, as of version 0.3.1 you don't need to explicitly initialize LSTMs. Quoting the official documentation: "If (h_0, c_0) is not provided, both h_0 and c_0 default to zero." See http://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.LSTM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that you are able to supply the initial state, it is a feature. They could have implemented it as a default but by letting you control the allocation of the tensor you can save some memory (allocating once, zeroing on every invocation).

Why would you need to set `h`? Sequence-to-sequence models require this (compress input to one vector, use this vector as hidden state for the decoder) or you might want to make the initial state learnable.

Comment: "You want to make the initial state learnable" -- But wont the intitial state get overwritten always before it is used in the next time step?

Comment: The initial state is only used once at the beginning of the sequence, yes. But maybe you want your network to learn a good initial value.

Comment: The "learnt" value will be discarded, for example, we learn a=3 is a good value, but instead of using it anywhere , we now say a=4. Because hidden layer value is calculated as a function as input and Weight matrix  and previous hidden [which is not there at time step 0] Then what is the use of finding that a=3 is a good value

Comment: The basic RNN formulation is `y_t = f(W*x_t + U*h_{t-1})`. The initial value `h` you pass into your RNN is `h_0` and is used in the very first computation: `y_1 = f(W*x_1 + U*h_0)`.

Comment: Don't we consider the first input y_0 ? If that is not the case ,then I understand everything and can accept your answer. Can you give some reference which states we start from 1 ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when typing down the formulation, the correct one is `h_t = f(W*x_t + U*h_{t-1})`. We start at `t=1` because otherwise we would have `h_{-1}` which would be a weird way to mark the initial state. This formulation is the typical "simple" (sometimes Elman) RNN and you can find plenty of references, e.g. [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2329.pdf).